# How to prevent code injection attacks in PHP?

Tags: php, code-injection

I am a bit confused, there are so many functions in PHP, and some using this, some using that. Some people use: `htmlspecialchars()`, `htmlentities()`, `strip_tags()` etc

Which is the correct one and what do you guys usually use?

Is this correct (advise me a better one, if any):

```
$var = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['username']));
```

This line can prevent MySQL injection and XSS attack??

**Btw, is there any other things I need to pay attention besides XSS attack and MySQL injection?**

**EDIT**

To conclude:

If I want to insert string to the database, I do not need to use `htmlentities`, just use the `mysql_real_escape_string`. When displaying the data, use `htmlentities()`, is that what you all mean??

Summarize:

- `mysql_real_escape_string` used when insert into database
- `htmlentities()` used when outputting data into webpage
- `htmlspecialchars()` used when?
- `strip_tags()` used when?
- `addslashes()` used when?

Can somebody fill in the question mark?

Comment: strip_tags() may be unsafe http://www.securiteam.com/unixfocus/5UP0C15DFI.html

Comment: You might be concerned with CSRF and directory transversal; the easy way to fix directory transversal is `basename(realpath($path))`.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

> - `mysql_real_escape_string` used when insert into database
> - `htmlentities()` used when outputting data into webpage
> - `htmlspecialchars()` used when?
> - `strip_tags()` used when?
> - `addslashes()` used when?

#### htmlspecialchars() used when?

`htmlspecialchars` is roughly the same as `htmlentities`. The difference: character encodings.

Both encode control characters like `<`, `>`, `&` and so on used for opening tags etc. `htmlentities` also encode chars from other languages like umlauts, euro-symbols and such. If your websites are UTF, use `htmlspecialchars()`, otherwise use `htmlentities()`.

#### strip_tags() used when?

`htmlspecialchars` / `entities` encode the special chars, so they're *displayed but not interpreted*. `strip_tags` REMOVES them.

In practice, it depends on what you need to do.

An example: you've coded a forum, and give users a text field so they can post stuff. Malicious ones just try:

```
pictures of <a href="javascript:void(window.setInterval(function () {window.open('http://evil.example');}, 1000));">kittens</a> here
```

If you don't do anything, the link will be displayed and a victim that clicks on the link gets lots of pop-ups.

If you htmlentity/htmlspecialchar your output, the text will be there as-is. If you strip_tag it, it simply removes the tags and displays it:

```
pictures of kittens here
```

Sometimes you may want a mixture, leave some tags in there, like `<b>` (`strip_tags` can leave certain tags in there). This is unsafe too, so better use some full blown library against XSS.

#### addslashes

To quote an [old version of the PHP manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20100525131537/http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php):

> Returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be quoted in database queries etc. These characters are single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash () and NUL (the **NULL** byte).
>
> An example use of **addslashes()** is when you're entering data into a database. For example, to insert the name *O'reilly* into a database, you will need to escape it. It's highly recommeneded to use DBMS specific escape function (e.g. mysqli_real_escape_string() for MySQL or pg_escape_string() for PostgreSQL), but if the DBMS you're using does't have an escape function and the DBMS uses \ to escape special chars, you can use this function.

The [current version](http://php.net/addslashes) is worded differently.

Comment: Thanks stefs - for me I needed a simple solution as the wider security complexity leaves me non producing code.
I am trying to have a simple script that reads a curl and takes out a specific image tag and url - along with a wordpress rss feed some news entries are created ready for the local site to consume. This is working in the webpage but I wanted to do this from a script and all of a sudden without my cms framework I am left with fear that I am making a big hole in our server for exploits. Do you know if its possible to do this from my server without exposing an api endpoint /get/news ty

Answer (score 10):

I thought of this quick checklist:

- **Always use HTTPS, without HTTPS your site is totally unencrypted**. And no, client-side encrypting things and sending them won't work, think about it. **Invalid HTTPS certificates also make you vulnerable to a [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attack**. Just use Let's Encrypt if you can't afford a certificate.
- **Always use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) on any output from your PHP code, that is, or contains a user input**. Most templating engines help you do that easily.
- Use HTTP-only flag in your `php.ini` to prevent scripts from accessing your cookies
- Prevent session-related problems

  - **Never expose user's `PHPSESSID` (session ID) outside the cookie**, if anybody gets to know a Session ID of somebody else, they can simply use it to login to their account
  - Be very careful with the `Remember me` function, show a little warning maybe.
  - Refresh session ID when the user signs in (or whatever appropriate)
  - Timeout inactive sessions
- *Never* trust a cookie, it can be changed, removed, modified, and created by a script/user at any moment
- Prevent SQL-related problems

  - **Always use prepared statements**. Prepared statements causes the user input to be passed separately and prevents [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
  - Make your code throw an exception when it fails. Sometimes your SQL server might be down for some reason, libraries like `PDO` ignore that error by default, and log a warning in the logs. This causes the variables you get from the DB to be null, depending on your code, this may cause a security issue.
  - Some libraries like `PDO` *emulate* prepared statements. Turn that off.
  - Use `UTF-8` encoding in your databases, it allows you to store virtually any character and avoid encoding-related attacks
  - **Never concatenate anything to your query**. Things like `$myquery = "INSERT INTO mydb.mytable (title) VALUES(" . $user_input . ")"` pretty much mean you have a huge security risk of an SQL injection.
- Store uploaded files in random, extension-less filenames. If a user uploads a file with `.php` file extension then whenever your code loads that file it executes it, and enables the user to execute some backend code
- Make sure you're not vulnerable to a [CSRF attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).
- Always update your PHP copy to ensure the latest security patches and performance improvements

Answer (score 6):

Only encode data at the point where it goes into the system it needs to be encoded for — otherwise you will run into situations where you want to manipulate the real data.

For SQL injection - use bound variables as described in [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php) (it talks about prepared statements, but it is the binding that gives you protection, not the preparation).

For XSS - if you are writing into HTML at point where either HTML or text is specified. Use htmlentities at the point where you generate your document. I would avoid storing the data in that form in the database (except possible in a write-rare-read-often system where CPU performance/disk access times were becoming and issue - then I would have a raw_ and an html_ version of the column … or just use memcached or similar).

If you are letting users enter URLs then you need to be more careful, as `javascript:do_evil()` is a valid URI that will execute (e.g. as an href for a clicked upon link or (in some browsers) the src of an image that is just loaded).

Answer (score 4):

**`htmlspecialchars()`**
turns `&`, `'`, `"`, `<`, and `>` into an HTML entity format (`&amp;`, `&quot;`, etc.)

**`htmlentities()`**
turns all applicable characters into their HTML entity format.

**`strip_tags()`**
removes all HTML and PHP tags.

Both `htmlspecialchars()` and `htmlentities()` take an optional parameter indicating how quotation marks should be handled. See the
PHP manual for specifics.

The `strip_tags()` function takes an
optional parameter indicating what tags
should not be stripped.

```
 $var = strip_tags ($var, '<p><br />');
```

The `strip_tags()` function will remove
even invalid HTML tags, which may
cause problems. For example,
`strip_tags()` will yank out all of the
code it thinks is an HTML tag, even
if it’s improperly formed, like

```
<b I forgot to close the tag.
```

Answer (score 3):

You only need to use mysql_escape_string() when inserting into a database and htmlentites when displaying the HTML. This is sufficient if you want to prevent a simple injection attack, but there are no doubt many other security issues you should be aware of when developing a web app, another major one being cross site request forgeries.

Comment: It is good you state this is sufficient to prevent simple code injections. For sensitive financial and medical information I would go further and suggest using PDO or Mysqli extensions. Ideally you want to use prepared statements and parametrized queries. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use htmlentities() when inserting data into the database or querying the database. If the data in you database is stored as entities, that data is then only useful to something that understands html entities.

You have to use different escaping mechanisms for different types of output, e.g. SQL - [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string), HTML - [htmlentities()](http://php.net/htmlentities) or [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars), shell - [escapeshellarg()](http://php.net/escapeshellarg). This is because the characters that are 'dangerous' are different for each one - there isn't a magic way you can make any data safe for any output medium.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this site [PHP Security Consortium](http://phpsec.org/). I found it to be a good site for an overall overview on PHP Security (SQL Injection and XSS included).

Comment: That site is seriously outdated nowadays

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but nowadays the most voted answer can be misleading for the beginners.

### As of 2017

1. You should never ever use mysql_real_escape_string. Even mysqli_real_escape_string is too weak to protect your database from the SQL injections. Instead of this, you should use PDO, and similar techniques. (see [that guide](https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection))
2. XSS (here I mean: `strip_tags()`, `addslashes()`, `htmlspecialchars()`, `htmlentities()`)  - here the most voted answer is still correct, but I would suggest reading [this article](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/06/preventing-xss-vulnerabilities-in-php-everything-you-need-know)

Comment: The year has little to do with the problem.  Your title should have read "As of PHP x.x", substituting the PHP version running on the host system.  Not all hosts can be assumed to be running the latest release of PHP.