# Preventing JavaScript Injection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, code-injection

Say i have a form with which user inputs some information and is submited to server using php and in PHP code i have say

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
// or
$data = strip_tags(@$_POST['data']);
```

1. I want to know of the `strip_tags()` is enough to stop javascript injection through html forms. If not how else can this be prevented. I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994974/php-javascript-mysql-preventing-javascript-injections).
2. And also say i input `javascript:void(document.bgColor="blue")` in the browser address bar, this changes the whole site background color to blue. How can javascript injection through the address bar be prevented.

Thanks.

Comment: Using the `filter_input()` and `filter_input_array()` functions are typically the better approach. You should completely avoid using the superglobals `$_GET` and `$_POST`, etc,

Comment: Not even famous websites have that strong protection. Facebook has a good protection, and it still can call function, depending on browser ofc

Answer (score 3):

i suggest to use `htmlspecialchars` when ever you want to output something to browser

```
echo htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

checkout [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: Thanks you very much. Your answer helped.

Answer (score 2):

For question `2`, I'm not sure if that's even possible to prevent. It's not something I've ever considered before. It sounds like you're trying to prevent executing any javascript that wasn't included by you on the page, which would also mean blocking the devtools in the browser from executing anything in the console. This could potentially be hostile to your users, e.g. if they wanted to use a bookmarklet from Instapaper.

For `1`, ultimately your goal is to avoid including this injected javascript from the form when you generate a new page. When you output the data from the form, you can wrap it in [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Comment: Thanks you very much. Your answer helped.

Answer (score 1):

It's depend which output you are trying to get.

In some cases , you'll want to leave the HTML tags including `script` tags ,**but** you want that those elements will not run when you output them, in that case you should use `htmlspecialchars($_POST['data'])`, (It's suggested to define also `utf8` as the third parameter).

But if you want to remove entierly the tags than `strip_tags` will prevent XSS

Comment: Thanks you very much. Your answer helped.

Answer (score 1):

One function cannot fully protect you from script injection. Consider the following program:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['height'])) 
  $height=htmlspecialchars($_POST['height'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
else $height=200;
if(isset($_POST['width'])) 
  $height=htmlspecialchars($_POST['width'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
else $width=300;
echo("
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe src='whatever' height=$height width=$width>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
");
```

The input is sanitized, but javascript will still be executed through a simple injection vector like:

```
300 onload=alert(String.fromCharCode(88)+String.fromCharCode(83)+String.fromCharCode(83))
```

You still need to quote your attributes or you are vulnerable like this example.

Another semi-common injection vector exists when user input is echoed into javascript comments, and you can inject new lines or close the comment. I blame it on the 'this shit doesn't work as it should, but let's keep it around in a comment'-style of development.

Note: The XSS protection of many browsers will not run my simple example. If you want to try it use one without protection, or find a vector that defeats it (not sure if there is one for e.g. Chrome).