# PHP printing search keywords

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP security question. As I am creating a PHP Webproject, I need to implement a website search and I am a little concerned about it's security. A while ago, I slightly remember hearing something about, that printing the keywords searched by the user (somewhere on the page), might cause that the website could get hacked.
Do any of you guys know anything about that?

Thanks for all the answers.

---

**BTW:** I already thought of getting rid of all eventually inserted HTML tags.

Comment: Search for XSS attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take into consideration [Cross site attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) as well as [HTML injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML_Injection)s and [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) when the user is adding the tag.

You should read:

- [How to prevent code injection attacks in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205889/how-to-prevent-code-injection-attacks-in-php)
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
- [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)
- [Survive The Deep End: PHP Security](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)