# How to safely print string with HTML tags and entities

Tags: javascript, php, datatables, xss

I have a string retrieved from MySQL database (escaped before stored in db),
stored as follows:

For example:

```
<script>alert(\'hi, im a bad injected script\');</script>
```

I attempt to print the stored data in a table enhanced by jQuery DataTables:

```
var dataString = data;
// data contains the string retrieved from database..

someDataTable.row.add([dataString]).draw();
// add/print the retrieved string to a table row
```

Hwever the webpage execute the data (script) printed in the webpage. how should I prevent this. I expect the page to print the script instead of executing it.

Comment: I believe `dataString = data.replace('<', '&lt;');` would allow the `<script>` snippet to be inserted as text without execution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1206461/2857264 - here is a good example to prevent sql injections.

Answer (score 1):

> **SOLUTION**

Use the following code to encode HTML tags and entities:

```
dataString = $('<div/>').text(data).html();
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3uegrqp/1/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score -1):

Store string using `htmlentities($str)`. It would convert html entities to character code.