# Sanitize backtick character in user input

Tags: php, shell, sanitization

I recently found out about shell injection and I have codes that executes user inputs in shell environment I need to sanitize the input so that there is no backticks or other malicious strings. Is it enough to use `str_replace()` and remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check link below
[How to prevent code injection attacks in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205889/how-to-prevent-code-injection-attacks-in-php)

you have plenty ways to achieve what you want. As you said "str_replace" can do the job. You can also use regex like

```
$Content = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i","",$Content);
```

Also you can use php_filters to validate inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Just replacing the backticks is not enough to safely pass a user-provided string to the shell, since there are other characters besides backticks that could cause trouble.

PHP has a built-in function you can use for that: [escapeshellcmd](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php)