# How do I store multiple similar data in a session array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I would like to be able to submit multiple times and store the data in a session array to be accessed in other server pages. I'n not sure how to do it.

```
<form action="Lab5-2.php" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><b>Customer Code</b></td>
      <td align="center"><b>Product Code</b></td>
      <td align="center"><b>Quantity</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"><input type="text" name="customer" required autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td align="right"><input type="text" name="product" required autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td align="right"><input type="text" name="quantity" required autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td align="right"><input type="submit" value="Submit" style="width: 80px"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You could append an array stored in a session. Have you tried that?

Comment: Is it something like array_push()?

Comment: Take a look at my answer below that should answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Lab5-2.php` you need to store like that:

```
session_start();
$postvariable=$_POST['customer'];
$_SESSION['customer']=$postvariable;
```

Obv for prevent Sql Attack use that [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205889/how-to-prevent-code-injection-attacks-in-php)

For you question on comment you can do that:

```
session_start();
$postvariable=$_POST['customer'];
$_SESSION['customer']=$_SESSION['customer'].','.$postvariable;
```

So for example you have insert product value "pc", then update next time have "mouse", you will have "pc,mouse"

Comment: But when I submit a new data, how do I make it so that $_SESSION['customer'] will hold the new data and also the previous data?

Comment: i add new part on answer.

Comment: Thanks , I found out I was calling function destroy() in the first page, that's why my data wasn't saving in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```php
session_start();

$_SESSION['data'][] = $_POST;
```

This should store all the `$_POST` data inside the session.

Use `print_r($_SESSION['data']);` to check if the data is appending to the session. This should do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: So I did that and whenever I submit new data, it will still overwrite the original data instead of adding the new data to the array.